# PL/pgSQL: Error at declare variable with case

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Im using "else" inside a case operator to declare a value into a variable through the value in a record.
Im trying to declare a value like that:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  rec_pessoa record;
  num_categoria_pessoa integer;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_pessoa IN SELECT * FROM pessoas LOOP
    num_categoria_pessoa = CASE rec_pessoa.cliente_tipo_clt_id
      WHEN 2 THEN 7
      WHEN 6 THEN 3
      WHEN 13 THEN 1
      WHEN 114  THEN 37
      ELSE NULL;
    END;
-- (...)
```

But getting this error:

```
psql:pessoas_table/3_transf.sql:414: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "THEN"
LINE 22:       ELSE THEN NULL;
```

Comment: The error is on line 22 (which you have hidden from us).

Comment: This `ELSE NULL; END;` is a problem. Not sure what `END;` is supposed to be terminating, if the the `LOOP` it should be `END LOOP`, if the `CASE` then it should be `ELSE NULL END;`, If the `BEGIN` then `ELSE NULL END; END;` Then there is the error message which is pointing at a different piece of code, `ELSE THEN NULL;`.